# WordPress Image Renamed

Tags: wordpress, file-rename, multisite, litespeed, media-library

I have a client who's multisite wordpress website renamed an image to another images name from a different  post.

The renamed image was the featured image, the name it was renamed to was a different featured image name.

Upon renaming, it added "-1" to the renamed image.

I have no idea how this could have happened. Has anyone experienced this before? If so how do I make sure it doesn't happen again?

We are using lightspeed caching plugin on a litespeed server.

I haven't tried anything since it has only happened once. We have uploaded many images after that and it hasn't happened since.

Comment: If you upload the same name image again n again then WordPress will add the `-1` suffix in the names of the image to keep the image urls unique.

Comment: No what I mean is, one featured image was names pumpkin the renamed image name was peach. peach got renamed to pumkin-1